# Yellow Window under JLabel when the mouse is above it -> how to remove?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I made a JLabel in a Jframe. If I now move my mouse over the JLabel a yellow small box appears([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWaJ1.png)). How can I disable this in Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an empty tooltip. You can turn it off by calling `setToolTipText(null)` on the JLabel.

Alternatively in a GUI editor you should be able to disable it from the properties of the JLabel. Look for a tooltip property.

Comment: Thank you, thats the solution!